# NodeJS: Converting uploaded video from Base64 to .mov file has problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, video, video-conversion

I have a form which a user uploads a .mov file. In the browser, this is converted into a Base64 string which is then stored in a text input as a value for that input. When the form is submitted, the server takes the value from the text input and uses writeFile() to store it as a file on the server. I need this to be able to play like a regular video, but instead, it is downloaded to my local machine. Below you can find examples.

What I want the file to behave like:

[Correct behavior](https://hubplus.org/assets/Videos/morris.mp4)

What the created file behaves like (gets downloaded):

[Incorrect Behavior (uploaded file)](https://hubplus.org/assets/Videos/last34655.mov)

Here is the code I use to turn the Base64 string into a file. This is a function within an express API endpoint.

var base64DataVideo = the base64 string of the video.

```
 var base64DataVideo = req.body.text[5].replace(`data:video/quicktime;base64,`, "");
var videoPath = "./public/assets/Videos/"+ req.body.text[0].replace(" ", "-")+req.body.number[1]+".mov"


fs.writeFile(videoPath, base64DataVideo, 'base64', function(err) {
  console.log(err);

});
```

Comment: More details, please. Is the file downloaded when the form is submitted? Can you share the code for the HTML form?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen no its uploaded to the server as base64 which is then used to create a file, the link to that file downloads instead of playing.